# Google Cloud Data Fusion is appending a column to original data

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

When I am loading data encrypted data from GCS source to GCS sink there one additional column getting added.

Original data
Employee ID,Employee First Name,Employee Last Name,Employee Joining Date,Employee location
1,Vinay,Argekar,01/01/2017,India
2,Thirukkumaran,Haridass,02/02/2017,USA
3,David,Wu,03/04/2000,Canada
4,Vinod,Kumar,04/02/2002,India
5,Joshua,Abraham,04/15/2010,France
6,Allaudin,Dastigar,09/24/2012,UK
7,Senthil,Kumar,08/15/2009,Germany
8,Sudha,Narayanan,12/14/2016,India
9,Ravi,Prasad,11/11/2011,Costa Rica

Data came to file after running pipeline

0,Employee ID,Employee First Name,Employee Last Name,Employee Joining Date,Employee location
91,1,Vinay,Argekar,01/01/2017,India
124,2,Thirukkumaran,Haridass,02/02/2017,US
164,3,David,Wu,03/04/2000,Canada
193,4,Vinod,Kumar,04/02/2002,India
224,5,Joshua,Abraham,04/15/2010,France
259,6,Allaudin,Dastigar,09/24/2012,UK
293,7,Senthil,Kumar,08/15/2009,Germany
328,8,Sudha,Narayanan,12/14/2016,India
363,9,Ravi,Prasad,11/11/2011,Costa Rica

First column 0 was not present in original file

Comment: To assist with the puzzle, I think you are going to have to describe the pipeline and detailed configuration of that pipeline.  Consider posting a recreate of the pipeline or else write up a Google Doc with screen shots and details and post a public accessible link to that document.  Without knowing how the pipeline was configured, I doubt there is much that can be offered in the way of advice.

Comment: Example consider I have taken 2 GCS nodes one from source and one from sink, for that first node i have provided bucket path which contains csv file and in second node i have given path where  this csv file needs to stored, in this case also extra column is getting added. Output file 0,0,Employee ID,Employee First Name,Employee Last Name,Employee Joining Date,Employee location
93,91,1,Vinay,Argekar,01/01/2017,India
129,124,2,Thirukkumaran,Haridass,02/02/2017,USA
173,164,3,David,Wu,03/04/2000,Canada
206,193,4,Vinod,Kumar,04/02/2002,India
241,224,5,Joshua,Abraham,04/15/2010,France

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are configuring the GCS source, did you specify the ***Format*** to be CSV or was it left as Text? When the Format is Text, the output schema actually contains an offset, which is the first column that first column that you see in the output data. When you specify the format to be CSV, you have to specify the output schema of the file.

Comment: Thank you , It worked , I have taken as Format as text and removed by offset in output schema, now that extra column was removed